# Rails 3: Get list of routes in namespace programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

### Question

How can I get a list of all the routes in my `Admin` namespace so that I can use it in one of my tests?

### Rationale

I frequently make the mistake of inheriting from `ApplicationController` instead of `AdminController` when creating new controllers in my `Admin` namespace. So, I want to write a test that visits all the routes in my `Admin` namespace and verifies that each one requires a logged in user.

Comment: Try running rake routes........it gives you all routes that you defined in your application

Comment: I'm am trying to use the list of routes in a test, so `rake routes` won't work for me. I need to be able to manipulate the list in code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
test_routes = []

Rails.application.routes.routes.each do |route|
  route = route.path.spec.to_s
  test_routes << route if route.starts_with?('/admin')
end
```

Comment: If you prefer, this can be a one liner: `admin_routes = Rails.application.routes.routes.select { |route| route.path.spec.to_s.starts_with? "/admin" }`

Comment: I would rather filter on the controller used, which would result: `Rails.application.routes.routes.select{ |route| route.defaults[:controller] == 'admin' && route.verb =~ 'GET'}` (with a filtering on the request type also).

Comment: You can also grab the `routes.spec` and call `.each` on it to loop through the tree. If you filter by `literal?` that will give you all the literal parts of the route which is often what I needed.

Answer (score 14):

In case anybody else wants to test that all routes in a namespace require a logged in user, here's how I accomplished it:

```
ROUTES = Rails.application.routes.routes.map do |route|
  # Turn route path spec into string; use "1" for all params
  path = route.path.spec.to_s.gsub(/\(\.:format\)/, "").gsub(/:[a-zA-Z_]+/, "1")
  verb = %W{ GET POST PUT PATCH DELETE }.grep(route.verb).first.downcase.to_sym
  { path: path, verb: verb }
end

test "admin routes should redirect to admin login page when no admin user is logged in" do
  admin_routes = ROUTES.select { |route| route[:path].starts_with? "/admin" }
  unprotected_routes = []

  admin_routes.each do |route|
    begin
      reset!
      request_via_redirect(route[:verb], route[:path])
      unprotected_routes << "#{route[:verb]} #{route[:path]}" unless path == admin_login_path
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      unprotected_routes << "#{route[:verb]} #{route[:path]}" unless path == admin_login_path
    rescue AbstractController::ActionNotFound
    end
  end

  assert unprotected_routes.empty?,
    "The following routes are not secure: \n\t#{unprotected_routes.uniq.join("\n\t")}"
  end
end
```

I welcome improvements.