# How to find where a view partial is used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

How do you go about easily finding out where a Rails view partial is used?

In what views, controllers etc.

This is handy when working on an app that someone else wrote. You don't necessarily know what views are using a particular partial, or where to find where the partial is used when navigating the app in the browser.

Currently, I am using the Sublime Text editor to project-wide search for the partial name "form" or "_form", or for "render ", but this gives an unnecessary amount of useless results.

Comment: If your _form partial is in (for example) the /users/ folder, use Sublime to search just inside that folder. Then, do a project wide search for "users/form" - that is the way other views will need to reference the partial. That will cut down on the amount of useless results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in solution, but I wrote a gem to try to solve this exact problem: https://github.com/Negotiatus/Partial-Finder

It's a rake task that will recurse through your project and attempt to create the full render chain (and routes!) for a given partial. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could try putting this [caller](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html) inside the partial, and then running your test suite:

```
#haml

- p caller[x]

#erb

<%- p caller[x] %>
```

I used `x` because you'll have to play around with which index you're calling to get useful information.

Comment: Don't have a test suite, I'm afraid. :( Good suggestion, though.

Comment: you could also click through your application and check your server output :)

Comment: yeah, as I said I don't now where to find the view partial in the app. There might be multiple places for all I know.

Comment: i thought you meant you didn't know all the places it is used...if you can't find the file, you need to make re-organizing this app you've inherited top priority.

Comment: I mean in the app in the browser. :)

Comment: ah, i see!  well, i mean if you add this 'caller' snippet, and then click through your app, you'll see all the places it's called via the server output

Comment: Yeah, I realized, but I don't know where to find, or even look for, the partial in the app (in the browser). I'd have to click through tens if not hundreds of pages :/

Comment: First work on having the caller call give you meaningful data.  Then take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19611104/2128691 You could write a simple script that gets every route, prints the route name, and visits it.  Then you'll easily see where this partial is used.